# Book with a kid who had a vanishing twin who stole his body

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read this story something like 10 years ago (I think it was fairly new around then), so I don't remember it too well, but the basic gist of the plot was this:

1. The kid isn't very personable or motivated, I think he gets bullied in the first chapter
2. He had a twin brother that died in the womb (a vanishing twin) (they talked about finding his teeth and hair at birth)
3. The parents are scientists, I think? They make an artificial body and somehow get his brother's artificial intelligence inside of it
4. They swap the twins bodies, so that the MC is in the artificial body and the twin is in his body

And that's how the book ends, I believe. It was horrifying as a kid for it to end on such a sad cliffhanger so I want to see if it had a sequel.

Comment: goosebumps the series

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure it wasn't goosebumps

Comment: If it were fantasy and about a pair of young women, it'd almost certainly be _Stranger With My Face_ by Lois Duncan. Which ends in a slightly different, but also memorably horrifying, way.

Comment: That sounds good, I'll have to check that one out. The book I was looking for was about boys tho, unfortunately

Comment: I think I've come across this book on Goodreads, but I can't find it now. Was it British, male author? I think it was part of series, but maybe the others books were standalones.

Comment: I’m sorry, I have no idea. I read it when I was like 10 or 11, I didn’t notice things like that back then

Comment: I googled some more and found this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167544/childrens-book-about-a-boy-with-a-benign-tumor-but-then-discovered-the-tumor-wa/181677 and with the names mentioned there I found the book (I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Lab 6" by Peter Lerangis

The [Google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=NdPGr86HbwQC) summary is:

> **Something is wrong in Lab 6—what are Sam’s parents hiding?**
>
> Sam Hughes has always been too smart for his own good. It’s in his
>   genes—both his parents are scientists who specialize in artificial
>   intelligence—and sometimes it gets him into trouble. Sick of the bully
>   who always steals his computer homework, Sam gives him a disk laced
>   with a virus as a prank. To escape the bully’s wrath, Sam runs and
>   hides in his parents’ lab. Inside, Sam hears a voice calling to him
>   from behind a locked door labeled “Lab 6.” His parents are in there,
>   and though he can hear them, he doesn’t understand what they’re
>   talking about. Are his parents hiding a body in their lab? Something
>   strange is going on, and Sam knows the answers lie somewhere in Lab 6.

Another from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1420038.Lab_6):

> Sam's parents are trying to extract his twin -- who's still inside
>   Sam's body.